# How to troubleshoot a first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have followed all the tutorial to connect and create a basic command. After hours of diagnosing, I still can't find out the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb 

Public Class Form2 

    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Databases11.accdb" 
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    Dim command As OleDbCommand 
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter 
    Dim sqlStr As String 

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sqlStr = "select * from Color"
        dt = New DataTable()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)
        da.Fill(dt) 
        da.Dispose()
        txtMID.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Color_Name") 
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's the error I'm seeing:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' 
>      occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: You need to read the exception message.

Comment: @SLaks yeap , the error is the one i wrote above. it have several line of the same error.

Comment: That's the type of the exception, not the message.  You have a `Catch` block somewhere in your code that it swallowing this exception.  Get rid of that and you'll find out what the problem is.

Comment: @SLaks how do i use the catch ? i am very new to this. haha

Comment: @SLaks is it possible he's seeing this inside the output window and this is actually an exception that's caught inside the framework and not passed onto the user? Would try/catch work in that scenario?

Comment: If no rows are returned, this line will throw an exception: `txtMID.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Color_Name")`

Comment: but i have data inside my database

Comment: @Noob9999 Yes, but it's a potential bug. Anyway, I believe Jeff's comment is the answer to your question. If not, please confirm.

Comment: @Noob9999 How/where are you seeing/getting the exception?